What does 'continued with the spread of central bank independence' mean in this context?
I am in doubt about the meaning for spread in the next lines:
Inflation has come down partly because many of the items we buy, from clothes to computers, have got cheaper as a result of technological innovation and the relocation of production to low-wage economies in Asia. It has also been reduced because of a worldwide transformation in monetary policy, which began with the monetarist-inspired increases in short-term rates implemented by the Bank of England and the Federal Reserve in the late 1970s and early 1980s, and continued with the spread of central bank independence and explicit targets in the 1990s.
Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 108). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
The author has been using this word to mean spectrum referring to different bonds' yield but this time, I do not think he's using it this way since I don't think there is a central bank called "Independence" and against which other yield could he be comparing the Independence Central Bank's yield or return, I mean the Independence's Central Bank's spread concerning what other debt instrument. I think he is using the "expansion" sense of the word in this particular context though I wonder if he is talking about other countries' central banks starting to have independence from their governments.

As the answer implies, it doesn't refer to 'a bank called Independence', but to the central banks of different countries.

[we don't say I am much in doubt, we'd say: I don't get or understand x very well]

Might you please explain why it is wrong to phrase it like that, I used this thread as a reference.
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-have-a-doubt-vs-to-be-in-doubt.3226373/

In the paragraph, the noun "spread" applies to both:

The spread of central bank independence:.    Many countries' central banks gained autonomy from their governments in the 1990s, enabling them to make monetary policy decisions without direct political interference.
The spread of explicit inflation targets: Central banks increasingly adopted inflation targeting during this period, setting clear and specific inflation goals. This approach helped anchor public expectations, reduce uncertainty, and enhance credibility.

This effectively captures the global trend in monetary policy during the 1990s, which transformed how central banks operated and made decisions.
Spread of Central Bank independence and explicit targets in the 1990s

Many central banks in emerging markets became more independent in the 1990s, including those in Mexico, Peru, and Poland. These central banks gained autonomy and adopted inflation targeting, a policy that adjusts monetary policy to achieve a specific annual inflation rate.

Source: World Economic Forum

Yes, spread in
the spread of central bank independence
takes sense 5 B2:

If something spreads or is spread by people, it gradually reaches or affects a larger and larger area or more and more people.

spread
The passage doesn't mention the countries involved, that is,
countries whose central banks are starting to have independence from their governments.

Sample:
It [inflation] has also been reduced because of a worldwide transformation in monetary policy, which began with the monetarist-inspired increases in short-term rates implemented by the Bank of England and the Federal Reserve in the late 1970s and early 1980s, and continued with the spread [move to the central banks of other countries] of central bank independence and explicit [inflation reduction] targets in the 1990s.
Here's an article that explains the independence of central banks:

Independent central banks that are able to conduct monetary policy
largely free from political interference have historically
demonstrated a strong ability to manage inflation. Central bank
autonomy is arguably the best monetary policy governance structure
ever devised, as illustrated by the experience of emerging markets in
recent decades.
In the 1990s, emerging markets such as Mexico, Peru and Poland
drastically recalibrated economic policy through a long and arduous
journey of economic reform. Central to these reforms was granting
autonomy to their central banks, which allowed many of them to adopt
an “inflation targeting” regime. This is the practice of adjusting
monetary policy to achieve a specified annual rate of inflation.

central bank independence
Please read the full article. Other countries were also involved.
The spread of central banks independence means the countries to which this independence came in response to existing economic troubles.

Thank you very much! I will read the article.
